# Action creator not called

Tags: reactjs, redux

Im not 100% sure if it is working correct, but it does noet give the result of the video course that I followed.

The `renderPosts` is just suppose to render the list, but instead it get a blank array the first time round. and when `mapStateToProps` is called the second time, the array is filled with the expected values.

it is as if the first time `mapStateToProps` is invoked, it did not pass through the action creator first or something.

**COMPONENT**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class PostsIndex extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log("componentWillMount");
        this.props.fetchPosts();
}

renderPosts() {
    // console.log("renderPosts - this.props.posts",this.props.posts);
    if(this.props.posts){
        return this.props.posts.map((post) => {
            return (
                <li className="list-group-itme" key="{post.id}">
                    <span className="pull-xs-right">{post.catagories}</span>
                    <strong>{post.title}</strong>
                </li>
            );
        });
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="text-xs-right">
                <Link to="/posts/new" className="btn btn-primary">
                    Add New Post
                </Link>
            </div>
            <h3>Posts</h3>
            <ul className="list-group">
                {this.renderPosts()}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("mapStateToProps",state.posts);
    return {posts: state.posts.all}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPosts})(PostsIndex);
```

**ACTION**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_POSTS = 'FETCH_POSTS';
export const CREATE_POST = 'CREATE_POST';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api';
const API_KEY = '?key=qwerty123';

export function fetchPosts(){
    const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`);

    return {
        type: FETCH_POSTS,
        payload: request
    };
}

export function createPost(props) {
    const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`, props);

    return{
        type: CREATE_POST,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

**REDUCER**

```
import { FETCH_POSTS }  from '../actions/index';

const INITIAL_STATE = { postsList:[], post:null };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
    console.log("action.type",action.type);

    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_POSTS:
            return {...state, postsList: action.payload.data};

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

mapStateToProps is called twice. on the initial call the array is empty. on the second call I have my ten posts inside the array.

Problem is that it seems to want to render the first array and ignores the second

I have put an consol.log in the

renderPosts
and

mapStateToProps 
and it renders as follows.

**Console**
[image]

any Ideas?

Comment: Can we see the action ? And the reducer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.udemy.com/react-redux/learn/v4/questions/1693796

In your reducer you're assigning the list of posts to the key `postsList`.

```
case FETCH_POSTS:
            return {...state, postsList: action.payload.data};
```

We can confirm that they are properly being assumed to `postsList` by looking at the `mapStateToProps` console log you have in your screenshot.

Your `mapStateToProps`, however, is looking at the property `state.posts.all`

```
return {posts: state.posts.all}
```

The list of posts are not assigned to the `all` property, they are assigned to the `postsList` property.  This is why you don't see the updated list of posts in your component.  You'll need to update either the property the reducer is placing the list of posts on or update your `mapStateToProps` to pull the list of posts from the correct property.

-Stephen Grider

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is coming from the way you handle the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). The first time you see the mapStateToProps in the console you can see you have no data so this is PENDING, the second is when it's FULFILLED. You need to find a way to handle this.

Example but not the best, I think you can just change you if statement.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class PostsIndex extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log("componentWillMount");
        this.props.fetchPosts();
}

renderPosts() {
    return this.props.posts.map((post) => {
        return (
            <li className="list-group-itme" key="{post.id}">
                <span className="pull-xs-right">{post.catagories}</span>
                <strong>{post.title}</strong>
            </li>
        );
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="text-xs-right">
                <Link to="/posts/new" className="btn btn-primary">
                    Add New Post
                </Link>
            </div>
            <h3>Posts</h3>
            <ul className="list-group">
                {this.props.posts !== [] this.renderPosts() : <h1>Loading...</h1>}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("mapStateToProps",state.posts);
    return {posts: state.posts.all}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPosts})(PostsIndex);
```

The second one should be by changing the way you do the promise. A good library is [redux-promise-middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware)

This is a example of my app what I did.

Actions

```
export const reqAllGames = games => {

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request
      .get(`${config.ROOT_URL}/${config.API_KEY}`)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(res.body.top);
        }
      });
  });

  return {
    type:    types.RECEIVE_ALL_GAMES,
    payload: promise
  };

};
```

Reducer

```
import * as types from "../constants/";

const gameReducer = (games = { isFetched: false }, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case `${types.RECEIVE_ALL_GAMES}_PENDING`:
      return {};
    case `${types.RECEIVE_ALL_GAMES}_FULFILLED`:
      return {
        games:     action.payload,
        err:       null,
        isFetched: true
      };
    case `${types.RECEIVE_ALL_GAMES}_REJECTED`:
      return {
        games:     null,
        err:       action.payload,
        isFetched: true
      };
    default:
      return games;
  }

};

export default gameReducer;
```

Component

```
const Games = ({ games, err, isFetched }) => {

  if (!isFetched) {
    return <LoadingCircular />;
  }
  else if (err === null) {
    return (
      <div>
        <GamesList games={games} />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <h1>Games not find!</h1>;
  }

};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => state.games;

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Games);
```

If you using react-router you can use the onEnter api and do the actions right here. With that you know your component gonna get the post. A good tutorial is this one from RallyCoding https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JicUNpwLzLY

Hope that can help you